# ¿Tuplas son inmutables? Entonces ¿cómo es que puedo añadir elementos?

Tags: python, tuplas

Estoy aprendiendo Python y consideraba que las tuplas son objetos inmutables. Pero he encontrado este código:

```
t = (2,3)
print(t)
print(len(t))
t = t + t
print(t)
print(len(t))
```

Entonces ¿cómo la tupla t pasa de tener 2 a tener 4 elementos? Como inexperto no entiendo cómo la tupla es inmutable pero se le pueden añadir elementos. Agradecería una explicación.

Comment: El signo `=` vuelve a crear el objeto. Una tupla es y sigue siendo inmutable, lo que pasa es que a la derecha de la expresión se realiza una operación y luego sobreescribe el objeto `t` con el resultado de una operación. Lo que no puedes hacer es, por ejemplo, `t[1] = 4` *'tuple' object does not support item assignment*

Comment: Como dice @aeportugal cambia **t = t + t** por **t += t** y nos comentas

Comment: Vale ya creo que lo veo. En realidad el código hace una reasignación que machaca al valor anterior que contenía la variable t. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Lo que solemos llamar *variables* en Python en realidad son punteros a objetos.
Todo son referencias.
Hacer una reasignación en Python significa cambiar el objeto al que cierta *variable* hace referencia.
Para ver el objeto al que una variable apunta podemos usar su `id`.
Una tupla sería mutable si pudiéramos cambiar su contenido, pero esto es imposible sin crear una nueva, es decir: sin obtener una nueva tupla con un nuevo `id`.

La expresión `t + t` devuelve una nueva tupla.
Puedes comprobar que `id(t) == id(t + t)` devuelve `False`, por lo tanto son objetos diferentes.
Al hacer la reasignación `t = t + t` estás poniendo la *variable* `t` apuntando a la tupla recién creada por el operador `+`.
A no ser que tengas más *variables* cuya `id` sea la misma que `t` antes de la asignación, ese objeto será borrado por el [Garbage collector](https://devguide.python.org/internals/garbage-collector/).

Ocurre lo mismo si utilizas el operador de incremento `+=`, que es sólo una forma más compacta de escribir exactamente lo mismo.